# Issue opening Shared folder files on network using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have developed an application using asp.net which should open files that are placed in a shared folder on the network, when I run the application locally it works perfectly (which means it opens any file that I click on),  but after hosting in IIS when I browse the application it gets the path of files in shared folder but cannot open any file, could anyone please help me in this regard?

I also used impersonation and all those steps but none solved my issue :(

Looking for your prompt help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Webserver code is not supposed to have wide open access rights.  It would be a security hole.  It typically runs as a user with minimum privileges confined to a few directories.

Comment: Thanks stark for your prompt reply,Could you please suggest me any solution to this issue?

Comment: One common method is to store the file in an upload directory under the webserver's control.  Have a separate privileged job run periodically that scans the directory and moves the files to the correct location